# Iphone - Do i need CCATS if I use encryption only for autentication

Tags: iphone, ios4, ios5

I am reading several posts on this issue but is still not clear. I am developing an app that uses sha encryption (with commoncrypto) for exclusively authentication reasons. For what I understood I do not need the CCATS documentation in this case and therefore I can overcome this procedure and simply send my app to apple without any further requirement.

Specifically I send an xml file (over soap) with the password encrypted and the extra data (like username, ecc) in clear. Additionally I do not communicate over SSL protocol

Is it correct?

Comment: SHA is not encryption, it is a secure hash - you can not get the input from the output; encryption can be reversed when you have the correct key.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only using CommonCrypto for your encryption functions you should not worry about this. You don't need the CCATS documentation, because it's already covered as part of iOS. It's generally accepted that any use of the built-in encryption functions does not require any disclosure - I don't believe Apple have ever officially published this as policy, but they certainly have communicated it to individual developers.

Comment: Unfortunately they've also communicated the exact opposite to other developers. I think you're _probably_ right but it's not completely clear.

Comment: You raise a good point: *legally* you should probably declare you use encryption. *Very few developers actually do*. If you ask Apple's compliance department they will tell you that you should tick the box. But if you were to ask someone from Apple off the record, they'd tell you not to bother (I have had a client who did this) . Technically, simply communicating with a third-party SSL web service would require you to fill out the compliance paperwork. I would be willing to make a fairly large bet that the vast numnber of apps using SSL on the store never went through compliance!

Comment: sorry but is sha an encryption? you are pointing out SSL protocol that is something different from sha algorithm.

Comment: Therefore I need CCATS documentation :-(